# JQuery/Firefox bug with textarea and .text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code can be tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/yWUTK/3/

```
<textarea id='textbox'></textarea>

<span onclick="$('#textbox').text('One');">One</span>
<span onclick="$('#textbox').text('Two');">Two</span>
```

Behaviour for this in Chrome and Firefox is the same, you click One or Two and it changes the textarea. However, on firefox, if you then manually change the content of the textarea, it no longer updates when you click. Chrome continues to work fine.

I'm running firefox 3.6.15

Can anyone explain this behaviour? I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if it's a genuine bug. My actual implementation uses proper markup and $(document).ready etc.

Comment: Why are you binding the click event *inside* an onclick attribute?

Comment: Updated, I have no idea what I was thinking lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are indeed correct, however, changing them to `val()` [works](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/yWUTK/2/).

```
<span onclick="$('#textbox').val('One');">One</span>
<span onclick="$('#textbox').val('Two');">Two</span>
```

`val()` is arguably the more correct method to use as well.

Also, I'm sure you are aware, you shouldn't use inline event handlers except in trivial examples like above.

Comment: However, you should remove the `$(this).click...` as on each click you are binding an additional click event. Just have `onclick="$('#textbox').val('One');"` instead.

Comment: Was that a recent change to JQuery? I was under the impression that val() did not work for textareas because the value is not represented the same as an input field

Comment: @Blair McMillan Yeah, I just copied the OP's example.

Comment: @SLC I believe jQuery abstracts that for you, much how `val()` should work by getting the `value` attribute of currently selected `option` with `select` elements.

Comment: @alex I know you did, however, assuming your answer ends up being marked as correct, we don't want people coming through later on copying the code which is "wrong". Also, the OP has updated the question now :)

Comment: @Blair McMillan Fixed, however `onclick` attribute still makes me cringe.

Comment: @alex As it should :) However, I think that's acceptable to keep there particularly with your note that you've added about how onclicks are bad.

Comment: @SLC, @Alex: `val()` **is** the correct method to use, since for a textarea it uses the `value` property, which is the only reliable way of setting a textarea's value. There's no "arguably" about it :)

Comment: @Tim Down It is the nice way of saying it :)

Comment: Can someone please elaborate on why text() is not working here? (just hit a similar problem)

Comment: @DavidBalažic Because the API for it says that the `value` property is used to update its contents.